# How to create custom grids in Foundation 5 that apply to all media queries?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I need to be able to create custom grids with more than the default 12 columns that I can apply to different elements in my markup (e.g. header, footer, section, etc). During my research I've seen a way to accomplish this by creating a mixin like this:

```
.app-navbar {
  $total-columns:18;
  @include grid-row();
  @include grid-html-classes($size:large);
    .columns {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

So this works fine but only when the large media-query is activated. When I resize my window to activate the medium and small media queries, this `.app-navbar` goes away and it goes back on the default Foundation 12 column grid. I understand that this is happening because I am passing `$size: large` into `grid-html-classes()`. How can I make this 18 column grid apply across all my media queries (small, medium & large)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wrap you styles in a media query the way to do it is like this:

`@media #{$small-up} { insert styles here }`

Have you tried editing your code like this?

```
.app-navbar {
  $total-columns:18;
  @include grid-row();
  @include grid-html-classes($size:small);
    .columns {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

The small declaration affects everything above it(medium, large).

Comment: Yes I've edited my code like in your example with the `small` declaration (w/o the media query bit) but  the small grid classes on all elements over ride the medium and large grid classes e.g. `small-3` will override `large-2` in the following: `<li class="columns small-3 large-2">`. Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Placing the custom grid declaration in media queries did the trick. Thanks :)